# psutil error in Python on FreeBSD

Tags: python, module, freebsd, bsd

I am trying to use psutil in a python script I'm writing on a FreeBSD system. At the top I have:

```
import _psutil_bsd
```

Then, when calling something like process_iter I have:

```
for process in _psutil_bsd.process_iter():
  if process.name == 'name_I_care_about':
    specialProcess = process
```

However I get the following error:

```
for process in_psutil_bsd.process_iter():
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'process_iter'
```

Any help would be greatly appreicated, Thanks

Comment: You need a space between in & _psutil_bsd in your `for`. So `for process in _psutil_bsd.process_iter():`

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo on my post, I do have the space in my code.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how psutil is supposed to be used. Why are you importing _psutil_bsd in the first place? Have you read the [doc](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation)?  The code is supposed to be:

```
import psutil
for p in psutil.process_iter():
    if p.name == 'name_I_care_about':
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `print list(_psutil_bsd)` to get of the list of symbols that are in the module.